# Kotlin LocalTime handle all different ways to parse AM/ PM

Tags: kotlin, java-time

Have an issue that my backend can receive 4 different formats for localTime. One as a 24h clock (without AM/ PM), one as AM/ PM, another one as am/ pm and as last a.m/p.m. Was wondering what the best way is to parse all those different formats inside kotlin.

Currently have this code:

```
class LocalTimeSerializer : JsonSerializer<LocalTime>, JsonDeserializer<LocalTime> {
    private val serializer = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
    private val formatters = listOf(
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm[:ss] a")
    )

    override fun serialize(src: LocalTime, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
        return JsonPrimitive(src.format(serializer))
    }

    override fun deserialize(jsonElement: JsonElement, type: Type, jsonDeserializationContext: JsonDeserializationContext?): LocalTime {
        formatters.forEach {
            val result = parseTime(jsonElement.asString, it)
            if (result != null) return result
        }
        throw DateTimeParseException("Could not parse localTime with value ${jsonElement.asString}", jsonElement.asString, 0)
    }

    private fun parseTime(time: String, formatter: DateTimeFormatter): LocalTime? {
        return try {
            LocalTime.parse(time, formatter)
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Which can handle the 24 hour clock and AM/ PM but was wondering how I can handle the other 2 cases.